# cannot find QtQuick controls palette

Tags: qt, qml, qt-designer

I have installed Qt Creator 5.12 using offline installer on Mac. As I start editing my qml file in design mode, all the buttons, controls and other stuff are dissapperad. I have added all the necessary imports in text editor (such as `import QtQuick.Controls 2.12`) and still cant see them on the link side. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out, that I neeeded to select 3D Preset Mode in order to see al the default components. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to View -> Views and make sure that Components is checked

[image]

If you didn't see the Components in the Views Menu. Maybe you got some error when downloading Qt, Try reinstall it

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I've already found solution ;)